# AWS cluster import own modules Import error in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, import

I want to run a python project on a remote server (AWS cluster).

In the project, there is a model ("model") in path project/folder2/model, in model.py I have df.write.parquet(parquetFileName).

In order for the salves to have that "model" from "folder2" I am using setup from setuptools.

This is my setup.py (path project/setup.py):

```
setup(
    name='dataFrameFromSpark',
    version='',
    packages=['project/config', 'project/folder2', 'project/folder3'],
    py_modules=['project/model1'],
    url='',
    license='',
    author='....',
    author_email='',
    description=''
)
```

Before running main.py I type this line on the remote server:

```
python project/setup.py build && python project/setup.py sdist && python project/setup.py bdist_egg
```

The error:

```
ImportError: No module named folder2.model
```

It seems the slaves don't get the folders when I run the  "write to parquet" code.

what can I do?